# node.js proxying with request: DELETE method not working

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, request

I need to forward any request starting with `api` to another server. I use `express` and `request` like this:

```
    var API_SERVER_HOST = "http://something.lala/output-api";

    // call the packages we need
    var express = require( 'express' );
    var request = require( 'request' );

    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;  // set our port
    var app = express();                  // define our app using express

    // all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
    app.use( express.static( 'webapp' ) ); // static content
    app.use( '/api', function( req, res ){   // proxying
        var url = API_SERVER_HOST + req.url;
        console.log(" - " + req.url + " => " + url + " " + req.method);
        req.pipe( request( url ) ).pipe( res );
    } );

    // launch
    app.listen( port );
    console.log( 'Magic happens on port ' + port );
```

So far, so good: `GET, POST, PUT` work like a charm, but `DELETE` methods end up with a bad request. The log is correct: proper url and delete method. If I copy paste the url of the log into a `curl -X DELETE`, it works like a charm.

Is request pipe not handling DELETE method ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those running into the same problem, I fixed my problem by using `http-proxy` instead of `requests` for forwarding. The code becomes:

```
var API_SERVER_HOST = "http://something.lala/output-api";

var express = require( 'express' );
var request = require( 'request' );
// use http-proxy instead of requests
var proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({ host: API_SERVER_HOST });

var port = process.env.PORT || 8088;  
var app = express();                 


// setup redirect
app.use('/api', function(req, res, next) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: API_SERVER_HOST
    }, next);
});

// listen to redirects (for logging purposes only)
proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    console.log("request : url=", req.url, req.body ? "body=" + req.body : "");
    console.log("response: status=", res.statusCode);
});
```

It works great for any type of request and handles perfectly body, query and url parameters.